# Free hand drawing on the iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I am pretty new to graphics but I want to create an iphone/ipad app that does free hand drawing. That is as the finger moves, a path is painted. Where do I start (books, resources, etc)? The stuff I see on apple's docs talk about lines and arcs. These are simple. They talk about bezier curves briefly. Is this what I should be looking into? Should I even be using quartz for this type of drawing since the number of interpolations would be very high (I presume) and thus make this type of drawing quite inefficient?

Thanks

Comment: You can try my answer. Just download code from link provided in tutorial & run it once.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/onmyway133/RoughSwift

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this using bezier curve.

I have written tutorial on it... check here. [iOS simple hand drawing](http://swapgo20.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/ios-simple-hand-drawing-with-eraser/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what you are attempting to do. We would really need more info on exactly the kind of app you want to make.

this tutorial is strong
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

You can do it in OpenGL and the drawing would be faster but it's more complicated to program.

I would use the touches to draw however you want, then composite that info into a the image rather than drawing a long sequence of shapes the user has made. This way you are only drawing the current shape and an image.